# Get Users Post ID

Tags: posts, front-end

I need a lil something done and I have looked over Google for and cant seem to find, not even a close solution.

My site is totally user front end with wp-admin being blocked by users. When a user logs in they are taken to a "dashboard".

Each person can only make one post. What i need is something to take the current logged in user and grab the post id of their post. so i can link to their edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that you didn't find references to the two components that you need. These are both extremely common.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$query = new WP_Query( 
  array (
    'author' => $current_user->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => array('any'),
  )
);
var_dump($query); // debug
```

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I wasn't looking to make a loop just to pull in 1 id. Otherwise i would have.